# useState working but value showing in the wrong way

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, progress-bar

The code im writing goal is to take the text input and convert the input into the relevant progression on a progress bar

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Multiline = (props) => {
  return (
      <TextInput
      {...props}
       maxLength={100} />
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Multiline 
    multiline
    onChangeText={setLoading}
    numberOfLines={20}
    style={{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "magenta",
    borderRadius: 10,
  }}
   placeholder={"Please enter text! "}/>
      <Progress.Pie
        style={styles.circle}
       // progress={}
        progress={loading}
        color={['magenta']}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around' , 
 },
  circle: { fill: 'transparent' },
});
```

The code works but the useState only works from 0.1 > 1 as the max value so when a user enters 0.1 into the text box its converted into 10% on the progress bar but i want the code to take 10 as a text value and convert that into the 10%. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
setLoading(e/100)
```

divide the value by 100 as the pie progress 1 to be 100%, so 0.1 becomes 10% and 1 becomes 100%